# Cannot find or open the PDB file while executing face recognition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

The below is my program...is this problem because of error in program...i am using Visual studio 2010 and ts linked with openCV...but while executing "Cannot find or open the PDB file" for many lines..what is the solution for this..

Comment: I  would like to get a program for face recognition system using rasperry pi board..program should be in C++..i have linked opencv on the board..the program must store 4 persons face as data base..and use haart classifier and eigen functions to create data base of 20 images of 4 persons seperately and must store their respective name..

Comment: the above is the training part..In the recognition part i need to recognise their face when seen on camera and give their name as output..if the person in front of camera is not stored,then "unkown Person" should be the output..I have usb camera for this..can anyone give the code for this algorithm that i gave..please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like berak said: don't worry about it. It's the same as all the `System` libraries, you can't look in to them but that's okay as long as it works.

When you need to check some code inside opencv, download the [source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) using Git. Open the project file and compile. Then include the output as library in your project. Then you will see the source code when hitting an `Exception`.

Comment: fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );
the above code should store facedata.xml..but i cant find any xml file..is there any problem..??

Comment: I am not familiar with openCV so I suggest to ask a new question for this to get the help from people who are more in to it.

Answer (score 3):

no fear, that's a warning, not an error, you're safe to ignore it.

yes, those pdb files are not supplied with the prebuild binaries, meaning - you still can debug your code, but you can't dive into the opencv libs while debugging.

if you really need this feature, you'll have to rebuild opencv locally ( build a sln for your box/env using cmake, then compile that sln ) , which will produce those pdb files as well.

Comment: i have no idea how I should rebuild opencv..can you tell the steps i must do to rebuild it so that I don't get any warning.

Comment: @berak: +1 for the answer.